# How do I link to another page within a Shopify Embedded App?

Tags: reactjs, shopify, shopify-app

I am building an embedded React app for Shopify.

I am trying to perform the seemingly simple task of navigating from one page to another.

For example, I would like to display a link on index.js that takes the user to newpage.js.

I have tried using Shopify's `<Link>` component (see https://polaris.shopify.com/components/navigation/link#navigation). However, when I click on the page I am presented with the following error:

`Expected a valid shop query parameter`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

By default the `Link` component from Polaris defaults to `<a>` tag that is not part of the react-router scope.

You need to overwrite the `Link` component with the react-router `Link`. This is done as a prop passed to the AppProvider component.

```
import {BrowserRouter, Link as ReactRouterLink} from 'react-router-dom';

<AppProvider linkComponent={Link}>
```

More on the matter can be seen here: https://polaris.shopify.com/components/structure/app-provider#section-using-linkcomponent

Comment: Thanks for your help, @drip. I'm still having some trouble with the code. I've opened a new question to build on this one (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66996055/how-do-i-use-routing-to-link-between-pages-in-shopify-embedded-app).